# Creating seed project of mean stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, seed

I have completed a project and i want to upload this project to GitHub, but this project including node modules also and i do not want to upload them too. I mean whoever clone project from git and type "npm install" can install packages already so it doesn't make sense to upload all of them.

So how can I create seed of my project, is there any framework for this?

Comment: `echo 'node_modules' >> .gitignore`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `.gitignore` file in the root folder of your project and add anything you don't want to upload to GitHub, like node_modules. Anything added to this file will be ignored by git.

```
# inside .gitignore
node_modules
```

If `node_modules` is already added and commited you have to remove the folder from git. Otherwise the folder will not be ignored even though it is in `.gitignore`.

```
git rm -r --cached node_modules
git commit -m "removing node_modules"
```